# Shimano M355 part broken

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, brakes, repair

Was riding my bike over a jump when i lost control and bailed. This led to a tiny part on top of the brake lever to snap and come off. Cant find any details on the part and its not on any diagrams or part lists. It looks like a little black, plastic screw with three bits coming down from it. Its the Shimano M355 Hydraulic MTB Disc Brakes. Picture attached, hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Ben[image]

Comment: Is it the pivot bolt, nut, and bushing that is missing ?  And the lever is flopping about ?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your right brake lever for comparison?

Comment: Yes the lever is flopping about a bit.

Answer (score 6):

I know what that is. It’s the pivot for the brake lever, and Shimano does not sell extras. Your options are:

- Buy a new brake system or lever (depending on which is cheaper. Used is fine as well. All Shimano MTB brakes are inter-compatible.)
- Go to your LBS and ask if they have a lever you can cannibalize. A friend of mine broke the exact same part and our LBS happened to have a spare lever they keep around for spare parts.

Be careful while fiddling with that 2mm hex fitting. It’s easy to strip out, and fixing that will definitely mean a new lever.

Comment: Thanks very much.